# Save all incoming emails to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, email

SO what I would like to do, is have all my emails routed to a PHP script, and then for that PHP script to save it to the correct staff members message box in my CRM.

My CRM is already able to send out emails but I cant seem to allow it to recive messages from customers.

My idea, is be able to keep track of which emails they are sending, and easy access to emails that need there attechion.

The Idea being there would be no need for them to open webmail or outlook.

Comment: What email server are you using?

Comment: I meant, are you using Postfix, Sendmail, Exim, etc. Which **email server software** are you using.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this tutorial and it worked for me (using Exim) with a little playing around:

http://www.evolt.org/incoming_mail_and_php

Note: the link seems dead so you might need to look up the Google cache:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6rwThYgNHe0J:www.evolt.org/incoming_mail_and_php+php+receive+email&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk